# How do I provide an implementation for a function type?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-function-type

Concerning function types in Kotlin
The following gives exception `kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property foo has not been initialized`

```
class SomeClass (){
    lateinit var foo: (String) -> Int
}  

val result : Int = c.foo("hello")
println("result $result")
```

The following 2 do not even compile

```
class SomeClass (){
    lateinit var foo: (String) -> Int = 1
}

class SomeClass (){
    var foo: (String) -> Int = 1
}
```

How do I provide an implementation for `foo`?

Answer (score 2):

You can declare `foo` function as val in this way

```
val foo: (String) -> Int = { someIntResult }
```

and use it like `foo.invoke("")` or if you need to use `lateinit var` you should initialize it later in class

Comment: Why would I use `c.foo.invoke("hello")` if I can just do `c.foo("hello")`? Also how would I initialize it later in the class?

Comment: @Jim yes you can use direct call of `foo("")` but it's clear when used `invoke()` that defines overloaded method. Initializing is `foo = { result }` where `result` is return value

Comment: Doing `foo = {1}` after `lateinit var foo: (String) -> Int` does not compile

Comment: @Jim You can initialize it in `init{...}`, inside `constructor(){ ... }` or  `fun(){...}`

Answer (score 1):

I'm really not sure what you're trying to achieve, but it should as simple as @StanislavBondar answer.

```
fun main() {
    println("Hello, world!!!")

    val test = Test()
    test.foo = { it.length }
    println(test.foo("ass"))
}

class Test {
    lateinit var foo: (String) -> Int
}
```

You can try it [here](https://pl.kotl.in/ry7PawEBN)
If it will still throw an `UninitializedPropertyAccessException` - most likely you're trying to access not initialized property (access before initialization, or access on another instance, etc.)

Comment: Thanks this helps. I am just trying to understand how to initialize it as I don't know Kotlin